# Get list "What to watch" video on Youtube using GTLServiceYoutube v3 on iOS

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I'm making an iOS app that allows users sign in Youtube and get some videos on it. There's an section called "What to watch".

How can I use GTLServiceYoutube class and GTLQueryYoutube to get the videos on this section

Below is the code that allows to get list uploaded videos, but I don't find the way to get list of What to watch videos

```
GTLServiceYouTube *service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];   service.APIKey = API_KEY;
   GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForPlaylistItemsListWithPart:@"id,snippet"];
   query.playlistId = UPLOADS_LIST_ID;
   query.maxResults = MAX_RESULTS; 
   [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
      if (!error) {
         GTLYouTubePlaylistItemListResponse *playlistItems = object;
         for (GTLYouTubePlaylistItem *playlistItem in playlistItems) {
            [self.identifiers addObject:playlistItem.snippet.resourceId.JSON[@"videoId"]];
         }
      [self getVideos];
     }else {
      NSLog(@"%@", error);
     }
   }];
```